# Populating Kendo component with data

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui

Officially got my first internship yesterday and I already have several tasks today and I have this Kendo dropdown which I have to populate with data.

I have this kendo dropdown which looks like this:

```
$("#products").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        dataValueField: "ProductID",
        optionLabel: "Pick one",
        // dataSource: data
      });
```

and this queryTask to get the data from a service that looks like this:

```
var query = new Query();
      var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://someService")
      query.where = "1=1",
        query.outFields = ["*"],
        query.returnGeometry = false
      queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {

      });
```

My data looks like this:

```
results[
   displayFieldName: "name"
   fieldAliases: "aliases"
   features: {c: null, attributes:{OBJECTID: 1, name: "name"} }
]
```

How should I get the `objectId` and the `name` into `dataTextField` & `dataValueField` into the Kendo component?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your results into something more usable like:

```
var results = {
displayFieldName: "name",
fieldAliases: "aliases",
    features: {
        c: null, attributes: { OBJECTID: 1, name: "name" }
    }
}
```

you can get it like:

```
$("#products").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: results.fieldAliases.features.attributes.name,
    dataValueField: results.fieldAliases.features.attributes.OBJECTID       
  });
```